# What can I do with this error? In regards with navigation thing in shinyapp

Tags: r, shinyapps

I have this problem with my project that it says "Error: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKol5.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKol5.png) <- this is the code I am currently working on, a Determinant matrix calculator

Comment: You will likely get more help if you copy/paste your code instead of sharing an image. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.